# how to register the unity container dynamically using dll?

Tags: c#, unity-container

is it correct?

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var RepositoryDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\CMI\Project CMI\CMC.StudentAccount.Taxation\App.Repositories\bin\Debug\CMC.StudentAccount.Repositories.dll");
var ServiceDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\CMI\Project CMI\CMC.StudentAccount.Taxation\App.Services\bin\Debug\CMC.StudentAccount.Services.dll");
var InterfaceDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\CMI\Project CMI\CMC.StudentAccount.Taxation\CMC.StudentAccount.Taxation.Interfaces\bin\Debug\CMC.StudentAccount.Taxation.Interfaces.dll");

Type IDatabaseFactory = RepositoryDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "IDatabaseFactory");
Type DatabaseFactory = RepositoryDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DatabaseFactory");
Type IUnitOfWork = RepositoryDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "IUnitOfWork");
Type UnitOfWork = RepositoryDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "UnitOfWork");

Type IEmployeeService = InterfaceDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "IEmployeeService");
Type EmployeeService = ServiceDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "EmployeeService");
Type IEmployeeRepository = InterfaceDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "IEmployeeRepository");
Type EmployeeRepository = RepositoryDLL.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "EmployeeRepository");

container.RegisterType(IDatabaseFactory.GetType(), DatabaseFactory.GetType());
container.RegisterType(IUnitOfWork.GetType(), UnitOfWork.GetType());

container.RegisterType(IEmployeeService.GetType(), EmployeeService.GetType());
container.RegisterType(IEmployeeRepository.GetType(), EmployeeRepository.GetType());
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? What it really does? Please describe the task you are trying to solve.

Comment: container.RegisterType<IEmployeeService,EmployeeService>();

Comment: instead of  register unity container like this Container.RegisterType<IEmployeeService,EmployeeService>(). i want  to register dynamicall at run time loading dll

Comment: Please, edit your updates into post, instead of adding the to comments. It also might be worth to read the "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" article and "[why 'is this correct' questions are off topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359466/why-is-is-this-correct-an-off-topic-question-and-what-should-i-ask-instead)"